# declaring a shared pointer of a template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have class template  that looks like below in my

`Counter.hpp`

```
template <typename T1, size_t Count>
class Counter {
public:

    explicit Counter();
    ~Counter() = default;

    void inc(T1 t, uint64_t val);

    void dec(T1 t, uint64_t val);

private:

    uint16_t array[Count];
};
```

in the `Main.cpp` file

I am able to create an object  like this:

```
Counter< MetricCounter1Type, countOfMetricCounter1Type()> myCounter;
```

and use the object .... but I want to be able to so something like a pointer declaration and create an object on the heap:

```
using counterp = std::shared_ptr <Counter>;

counterp myCounter1p = std::make_shared<Counter<T1type, n>>;
counterp myCounter2p = std::make_shared<Counter<T2type, m>>;
```

I understand its sort of trivial question, being new to templates and shared pointers , there are too many things to wrap your head around

SO basically the question is can you create a generalized shared pointer type like above and instantiate objects?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` requires a type parameter. `Counter` is not a type. Can you create a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector>`? What would such a thing mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Counter` is a *class template* that takes two *parameters*, i.e.: this class template is parameterized by `T1` and `Count`. A class type is generated from this class template by providing arguments to those parameters.

Assuming that any of the arguments you are passing to the class template is different from each other, i.e.: `T1type` is different from `T2type` or `n` is different from `m`, then `Counter<T1type, n>` and `Counter<T2type, m>` are different types. Therefore, the objects generated by:

```
std::make_shared<Counter<T1type, n>>();
std::make_shared<Counter<T2type, m>>();
```

have different type as well. So, you can't define a common (non-templatized) type to store any of the two objects.

---

Note that your `counterp` *type alias* won't compile:

```
using counterp = std::shared_ptr<Counter>;
```

because `Counter` didn't receive the two template arguments it requires to become a type.

You can however define an *alias template*:

```
template<typename T1, size_t Count>
using counterp = std::shared_ptr<Counter<T1, Count>>;
```

and then provide `couterp` with the two template argument it requires:

```
counterp<T1type, n> myCounter1p = std::make_shared<Counter<T1type, n>>();
counterp<T2type, m> myCounter2p = std::make_shared<Counter<T2type, m>>();
```

Note again that `counterp<T1type, n>` and `counterp<T2type, m>` can be different types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auto`

```
auto myCounter1p = std::make_shared<Counter<T1type, n>>;
auto myCounter2p = std::make_shared<Counter<T2type, m>>;
```

Or [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

```
template<typename T1, size_t Count>
using counterp = std::shared_ptr <Counter<T1, Count>>;
...
counterp<T1type, n> myCounter1p = std::make_shared<Counter<T1type, n>>();
counterp<T2type, m> myCounter2p = std::make_shared<Counter<T2type, m>>();
```